# How to restrict controller/view access based on domain ad group

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I want to restrict certain parts of my web app to certain user groups located in AD groups inside our domain.

I am using .Net Core 1.1. I have also tried decorating my controller with the [Authorize] attribute but with little success.

Does .Net Core currently have a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you pass windows authentication token with in your `Services`:

```
services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ForwardWindowsAuthentication = true;
            });
```

And then use the `[Authorize]` attribute as follows
`[Authorize(Roles = "AD Role")]`